# Wordpress Mobify mobile theme, CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, mobify

I'm having a hard time with a wordpress mobile theme named mobify. I need the theme to display each of the posts in a mobile browser with full text and picture, but it only does that for the first 2 posts. Me being a web developer and not too familiar with Wordpress have looked at the html code and tracked the culprit down to the tag that's present in the first two posts and not in the rest. It's

```
<div class="entry">
```

I'm pretty sure I can find a way to hack this css class into the backend of the Wordpress script, but I'm asking the experts, what's the Wordpress way to modify the script so it's present in every subsequent post after?

Comment: In admin in Settings / Reading, how much posts "Blog pages (should) show at most"? Is it 2? Or can you see a theme file using `the_content()` for the first 2 posts displayed by the Loop and then `the_excerpt()`?

Answer (score 0):

Peter here -- I'm the Chief Architect at Mobify.  The Wordpress plugin has been deprecated & discontinued for some time.  We did indicate that in the plugin page -- but I realize there are still some blogs / sites that have direct links.

We still support Wordpress, and every content management platform.  There's just no longer any need for a platform specific plugin -- we can support every platform using a simple HTML tag inserted into the page.  [Give us another look.](http://www.mobify.com) Feel free to get in touch if you have further questions.

Comment: Greetings Pete. As far as we are glad to have you here on Stackoverflow please take sometime to read the FAQ to see what type of answer you can provide in this area. Thanks